# KeeperErrorCode NoNode for /config/changes/isr_change_0000XXXX

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We have a CDH cluster with kafka 0.8.2 and zookeeper 3.4.5, recently zookeeper reported exceptions continuously like:

```
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x3660f87a92d007a type:delete cxid:0x26d8715 zxid:0x102231be7 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/config/changes/isr_change_0000007493 Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /config/changes/isr_change_0000007493
```

Although the exception is `INFO` level, but there are too many exceptions only change the number after  `/config/changes/isr_change_`. 
How can I deal with it? Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already pointed out, these are not errors since their log level is `INFO`. 
Such logs simply inform you that Kafka tried to create a particular node that already exists which is a normal behaviour for Kafka. Therefore, you should not worry about them.